# Compare two kernel config files from the menuconfig perspective?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, configuration, make

I have a situation in which i have two kernel config files (for the same kernel source ). Both of them have a part of the functionality that i need (on one, USB works correctly, on other, the second I2C).

I know that the differences between the two config files, from the perspective of menuconfig,  include only a few selected options. (But don't know which ones)

However when the config files are manually compared (meld between two .config files), the differences are not simple to identify. I have tried merging them manually without success. I'm sure I'll succeeded eventually but believe the process could be much more painless if the files were compared in a way they appear in the menuconfig.

Can this be achieved, and if so, how?

Answer (score 23):

Try using [`scripts/diffconfig`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/scripts/diffconfig) from the Linux kernel source tree.

Usage:

```
diffconfig config-a config-b
```

Shows a list of lines removed, modified and added to the config-b file with respect to config-a.

Answer (score 10):

There is a script in the kernel source;

```
scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh
```

It will take 2 kernel configs as arguments - it will merge the 2nd on top of the first. Anything in the 2nd config will override the first config - even if it is a line like "# CONFIG_ is not set"

See http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Quick_start_with_3.14_linux

Answer (score 5):

If the two files are generated by `make menuconfig`, they will have the options in the same order, so a simple `diff` (via Meld or whatever frontend you like) will give a usable result.

You might get something more readable if you ignore comment lines:

```
diff -I '^#' old.config new.config
```

If for some reason the files aren't in the same order, you could sort them. This has the downside of putting related options far apart. Again, remove comments. Use [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) to strip off the common lines.

```
comm -3 <(<old.config grep '^[^#]' | sort) <(<new.config grep '^[^#]' | sort)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try `sort`ing the files before comparing:

```
meld <(sort config-a) <(sort config-b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `kdiff3` to compare two configs.

If anyone wants to compare .config (current configuration) file to some default configuration from kernel tree, first export defconfig from current configuration:

`make savedefconfig`

This will export defconfig file, which can be easily compared to any other default configuration file.